Does a Berghaus Air Tent Porch work with a QUECHUA Air Seconds 4.1?
I wish to both prevent rain running into the tent from the sloping door when it is opened and provide a dry area (without ground sheet for a chair that my disabled wife can use to remove shoes. It would be a shame to replace a nearly new tent with a Berghaus tent so we can fit a porch.

Have you contacted Berghaus and asked?

I tried to visualize what you want, and how the two components would go together, and failed, even when I looked up pictures of Berghaus and Quechua tents.  But then I am not good at 3D visualization.   My impression from the pics I saw is that the Berghaus is large tent with rooms, and the Quechua is a more ordinary tent.  You might get a response if you had a picture and/or a sketch of what you want the resultant structure to look like.   I understand that you need more than a rain fly, but am not sure how much more than a rain fly you need.

@ab2, the Berghaus porch is a seperate self surported  "room"  that have a fly that pitches over the roof of the main tent.  I would wish to put it at the front of my tent, rather than on the sidedoor as is normally shown in photos.

Welcome to TGO. Ideally, questions should stand on their own, without comment.
Certainly, some pictures would help explain your question/predicament.
Please [edit] all extra information, including what you provided in comments, into the body of the question.
